# Amazon S3 download try limit

Tags: amazon-s3

I want to restrict download try to certain number from my Amazon s3 service

I am using library from http://undesigned.org.za/

Any one is having any idea how can I restrict download to certain number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that this restriction is impossible -- can't be done.

A number of other S3 users would like to limit the amount of traffic that their account can generate, in order to limit service costs. This is equivalent to restricting the number of downloads.

S3 budget control was a requested feature back in 2006.

Still no word from Amazon AWS on the thread below, which  tracks this request to add a feature to S3 where accounts will turn off access when a budget is reached. The thread which runs up to the present day, contains ideas for workarounds amidst the complaints:

See https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=10532&start=25&tstart=0

Several third party solutions are mentioned.

Comment: Amazon recently added "billing alerts" that might help monitor for over-usage:  http://www.amazon.com/gp/r.html?R=DMBFBU0Q6PVM&C=1CGFDLPZUE0DY&H=VR7CWUPDAKSNAJZYFAMYPOLLOA4A&T=C&U=https%3A%2F%2Faws-portal.amazon.com%2Fgp%2Faws%2Fdeveloper%2Faccount%2Findex.html%3Fie%3DUTF8%26action%3Dbilling-alerts%26%26ref_%3Dpe_12300_23933880