# Cloud File Storage with Bandwidth Limits

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, architecture, storage

I want to develop an app for a friend's small business that will store/serve media files. However I'm afraid of having a piece of media goes viral, or getting DDoS'd. The bill could go up quite easily with a service like S3 and I really want to avoid surprise expenses like that. Ideally I'd like some kind of max-bandwidth limit.

Now, the solutions for S3 this has been [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39473419/limiting-amazon-s3-downloads-service?noredirect=1&lq=1)
But it does require quite a few steps. So I'm wondering if there is a cloud storage solution that makes this simpler I.e. where I don't need to create a custom microservice. I've talked to the support on Digital Ocean and they also [don't support this](https://ideas.digitalocean.com/ideas/CDNX-I-9)

So in the interest of saving time, and perhaps for anyone else who finds themselves in a similar dilemma, I want to ask this question here, I hope that's okay.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not an out-of-the-box solution, but you could:

- Keep the content **private**
- When rendering a web page that contains the file or links to the file, have your back-end generate an [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) to grant time-limited access to the object
- The back-end could **keep track of the "popularity" of the file** and, if it exceeds a certain rate (eg 1000 over 15 minutes), it could instead point to a small file with a message of "please try later"

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation!
Ideally there will be a public RSS feed for videos/audio files. So I think the URLS will have to be public